# How to use flutter doctor again

Tags: flutter, dart

I used flutter doctor but I forgot to install android studio. Then I again installed it but the same summary is appearing[image]

Comment: Open a new terminal and try it again, or set the path of the Android SDK.

Comment: Terminate the current terminal, run the command in new terminal window.
Check if you have multiple versions of Android Studio installed (as one of my friends did), this causes the same problem to happen. Remove unnecessary versions.
Check Android SDK Path.

Comment: Did you, as the text tells you, actually run android studio and follow the instructions in the second link? Or did you just read the first link and installed it and come back to run flutter doctor?

Answer (score 0):

you are android  studio  licences   command Run on   Terminal

like this Command  flutter doctor –android-licenses

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).